# Elevation maps from point clouds: TPS vs. other methods?

Tags: dem, interpolation, lidar, references, spline

[In the reply to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91999/27719), @thehealingprocess refers to

> "...a comparison of interpolation methods for interpolating elevation maps
>   from LiDAR clouds, and in almost all scenarios thin plate spline
>   interpolation was the most accurate method. IDW is good in some
>   situations but it's quite primitive."

Does anyone have a reference to such a survey?

Answer (score 4):

Evans, Jeffrey S.; Hudak, Andrew T.  2007.  [A multiscale curvature algorithm for classifying discrete return LiDAR in forested environments](http://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2007_evans_j001.pdf).   IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing. 45(4): 1029-1038.

---

Look on Table II (page 1034). The authors tested different interpolation methods to define the best way to classify ground returns with their algorithm (MCC):

- ordinary kriging (OK),
- inverse distance weighting (IDW),
- triangular irregular network (TIN) and
- thin plate splines (TPS).

TPS was the best method when compared with field data samples.